# MySql: assign variable a random number using RAND(seed)

Tags: mysql, random, stored-functions

I am trying to do something I think is pretty simple, just use RAND to create a random number between 0-1, and assign it to a decimal variable.
BUT every time I run my code in MySQL it gives back ZERO!

See code below:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `myfuncRand`() RETURNS decimal(10,5)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE dist decimal;
set dist = RAND(145);
RETURN dist;
END$$


select myfuncRand();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues.

A column or procedure variable declared as DECIMAL will have default value for "number of digits" (i.e. precision) and "number of digits to the right of the decimal point" (i.e. scale) assigned.

```
`DECIMAL` is equivalent to `DECIMAL(10,0)` which is no digits to the right of the decimal point.
```

And when values are assigned, they will be "truncated" or "rounded" to the appropriate scale, the exact behavior is dependent on the operating system.

As a second point, the MySQL expression **`RAND(145)`** does not produce a pseudo-random number; it will produce the exact same number everytime it is called. The value supplied as an argument is a "seed" value, specifies a starting point for the pseudo-random series. (The series is not truly random, it just appears to be random.

When this statement is run, it will return the same value repeated:

```
SELECT RAND(145), RAND(145), RAND(145), RAND(145)
```

When this statement is run, it will produce the same series every time it's run:

```
SELECT RAND(145), RAND(), RAND(), RAND(), RAND()
```

---

So, two things to fix.

The declaration of `dist` procedure variable should specify precision and scale, e.g.:

```
DECLARE dist DECIMAL(10,5);
```

(the selection of values for precision and scale here are intended to match the datatype the function is declared to return. If we only need five digits after the decimal point, DECIMAL(6,5) would suffice.)

and:

```
SET dist = RAND();
```

Repeated calls to the `RAND()` function  will produce a series of pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: Thanks spencer7593, it worked. The dist decimal was the issue as you said, the default did not produce decimals. Thanks so much for the answer and for posting this answer so quickly. Sincerely P.